# Can I save Installation logs in a text file?

Tags: system-installation, log

When we install Ubuntu, while it's coping files there are lot of processes going on, it's downloading a lot of files, their is a lot of useful information in there, can I save those logs in a text file

[image: Screenshot]

*This is the log i'm talking about, might look a little different because it's a different flavour of Ubuntu*

Comment: Doesn't look like an official flavor?

Comment: @DKBose It's Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 (the official one)

Comment: Look at file `/var/log/apt/term.log`; maybe you find the output there?

Comment: @ridgy this is apt-get repository not the original system-installation log